# ServiceStack Request Body

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to write my 1st REST service in servicestack and ormlite. It's not going too bad.

I have managed to write the code that displays all records, records based on and ID and delete a record based on an ID.

Now I am moving onto adding and editing a record and I am getting confused about how to get the data from the request body of the call.

I am doing a

```
POST: http://localhost:7571/equipment/create/123
```

with the request body of

```
[{"eMCo":"1","equipment":"DP112","location":"Field","manufacturer":"","model":"","modelYr":"2013","vinNumber":"","description":"Trevor","status":"A","attachToEquip":"BR118","licensePlateNo":""}]
```

But in my service I cannot work out how to access the request body data in this function:

```
public object Post(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            //base.Request.FormData[""]
            db.Insert(request);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is the complete code... If you can point out ANYTHING I am doing wrong please do !

```
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ViewPoint
{
[Api("Enables viewiing, creation, updating and deletion of equipment from the EMEM table.")]
[Route("/equipment", "GET")]
[Route("/equipment/detail/{equipment}", "GET")]
[Route("/equipment/delete/{equipment}", "DELETE")]
[Route("/equipment/update/{equipment}", "PATCH")]
[Route("/equipment/create/{equipment}", "POST")]

public class EMEMTrev
{
    public string eMCo { get; set; }
    public string equipment { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string ModelYr { get; set; }
    public string VINNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string AttachToEquip { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlateNo { get; set; }
}

public class EMEMTrevResponse
{
    public string eMCo { get; set; }
    public string equipment { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string ModelYr { get; set; }
    public string VINNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string AttachToEquip { get; set; }
    public string LicensePlateNo { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
}


public class EquipmentService : Service
{
    public object Get(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            if (request.equipment == null)
            {
                List<EMEMTrev> results = db.Select<EMEMTrev>();
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                List<EMEMTrev> results = db.Select<EMEMTrev>(p => p.Where(ev => ev.equipment == request.equipment));
                return results;
            }

        }
    }
    public object Delete(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.Delete<EMEMTrev>(p => p.Where(ev => ev.equipment == request.equipment));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object Post(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            //base.Request.FormData[""]
            db.Insert(request);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object Patch(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.Update(request);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

**UPDATED CODE:**

ServiceEquipment.cs

```
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

namespace ViewPoint
{
[Api("Enables viewiing, creation, updating and deletion of equipment from the EMEM table. Use a POST to create an EMEM or a PUT to update one.")]
[Route("/equipment", "GET,POST,PUT")]
[Route("/equipment/{equipment}", "GET,DELETE")]

public class EMEMTrev
{
        public string eMCo { get; set; }
        public string equipment { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string manufacturer { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string modelYr { get; set; }
        public string vinNumber { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string attachToEquip { get; set; }
        public string licensePlateNo { get; set; }

}

public class EMEMTrevResponse
{
    public EMEMTrev emem { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; } //Where Exceptions get auto-serialized
}


public class EquipmentService : Service
{
    public object Get(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
                    using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            if (request == null)
            {
                List<EMEMTrev> results = db.Select<EMEMTrev>();
                return results;
            }
            else
            {
                List<EMEMTrev> results = db.Select<EMEMTrev>(p => p.Where(ev => ev.equipment == request.equipment));

                return results;
            }

        }
    }
    public object Delete(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.Delete<EMEMTrev>(p => p.Where(ev => ev.equipment == request.equipment));
        }
        return new HttpResult
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
            Headers =
                           {
                               {HttpHeaders.Location, this.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(request.equipment)}
                           }
        };
    }

    public object Post(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.Insert(request);
        }
        return new HttpResult()
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created,
            Headers =
                           {
                               {HttpHeaders.Location, base.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(request.equipment)}
                           }
        };
    }

    public object Put(EMEMTrev request)
    {
        var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Kent;Integrated Security=True", SqlServerDialect.Provider);
        using (IDbConnection db = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            db.Update(request);
        }
        return new HttpResult
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent,
            Headers =
                           {
                               {HttpHeaders.Location, base.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(request.equipment)}
                           }
        };
    }
}
```

}

AppHost.cs:

```
using System.Configuration;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Auth;
using ServiceStack.Configuration;
using ServiceStack.Data;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ViewPoint.App_Start.AppHost), "Start")]


/**
* Entire ServiceStack Starter Template configured with a 'Hello' Web Service and a 'Todo' Rest Service.
*
* Auto-Generated Metadata API page at: /metadata
* See other complete web service examples at: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples
*/

namespace ViewPoint.App_Start
{
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{       
    public AppHost() //Tell ServiceStack the name and where to find your web services
        : base("StarterTemplate ASP.NET Host", typeof(EquipmentService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        //Configure User Defined REST Paths
        //Routes
        //  .Add<Hello>("/hello")
        //  .Add<Hello>("/hello/{Name*}");

        //Uncomment to change the default ServiceStack configuration
        //SetConfig(new HostConfig {
        //});

        //Enable Authentication
        //ConfigureAuth(container);

        //Register all your dependencies
        //container.Register(new TodoRepository());         
    }

    /* Example ServiceStack Authentication and CustomUserSession */
    private void ConfigureAuth(Funq.Container container)
    {
        var appSettings = new AppSettings();

        //Default route: /auth/{provider}
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings), 
                new BasicAuthProvider(appSettings), 
            })); 

        //Default route: /register
        Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature()); 

        //Requires ConnectionString configured in Web.Config
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppDb"].ConnectionString;
        container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(c =>
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider));

        container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c =>
            new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

        container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: First thing I notice is that your JSON sample is an object inside an array: `[{...}]`, but your request DTO is a plain object. Does your application behave better if you remove those square brackets so your JSON looks like `{...}`?

Comment: @esker thanks - tried that. no change :(

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please what the exact problem is then? Is your `request` object in the `Post` request null, even after removing the square outer brackets from the request JSON? Or are there individual properties in the `request` object that are unexpectedly null? Or is the `Post` method not even being called when you send a request? etc.

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I am confused why you want access to the raw body data at all. Particularly if the raw data you are sending is JSON, and that is deserialized automatically to the request parameter for your method. If you send valid JSON then your data should be accessible using `request.Description` or `request.ModelYr` etc. What client are you using to send the request?

Comment: @Scott Hi, you may have spotted my error. when I call POST: http://localhost:7571/equipment/create/123 I can see the "123" but I cannot see "description" for example - it's empty, which is why I thought I had to do something to read the request body?

The client? - I have been trying to call the function with Fiddler

Comment: @esker yes, even when I remove the square outer brackets my request values are still null... I just cannot work out what's going wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is to do with the case difference between your JSON data and your DTO. The mapping is case sensitive. The `equipment` parameter is populated because the case matches, but the rest of the properties don't.

You can solve this by adding this line to your `AppHost` Configuration.

```
JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
```

This sets the serializer to map the `location` in your JSON data to `Location` in your DTO *and the other properties*, and handles the conversion back when you serialize.

So you can then access the property on the request parameter, and not through the raw data.

---

Your service looks OK. I can't immediately see any issue with it, I think the issue may then lie with how you are calling the service.

These methods below will help with debugging the issue. I recommend that you try calling the client using this simple HTML page, and see if you get the required fields populated.

Create a file, call it `test.html` and put it in the `bin` folder with your ServiceStack service assembly, and navigate to your service path `http://localhost:7571/test.html`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function send()
            {
                // Send data to the service
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/equipment/create/DP112",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        eMCo: "1",
                        equipment: "DP112",
                        location: "Field",
                        manufacturer: "",
                        model: "",
                        modelYr: "2013",
                        vinNumber: "",
                        description: "Trevor",
                        status: "A",
                        attachToEquip: "BR118",
                        licensePlateNo: ""
                    })
                }).done(function(result){

                });
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="send()">Send Request</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This html file should provide a properly formed request.

Also consider adding the Request Logger, by adding this line to your AppHost Configure. Then go to `http://localhost:7571/requestlogs`. [See here](https://docs.servicestack.net/request-logger) for more information.

```
Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());
```

---

### Request ContentType:

If the correct content type is not set on the client request then ServiceStack will not populate the values into the request. Setting the `contentType` on the request to `application/json` works.

Comment: weird. I already have that in my apphost... and still cannot see the values coming in... ill keep looking. must be something silly I am doing...

Comment: @TrevorDaniel Can you update your Question to include your AppHost config?

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I have updated my answer to help provide debugging instructions.

Comment: unbelievably the request is still empty! - im stumped

Comment: I have added the plugin in apphost.cs in the ConfigureAuth and I get a 404 trying to get to /requestlogs - I must have done something in a previous life to upset SS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45114/discussion-between-scott-and-trevor-daniel)

Comment: Scott is the man! we were both stumped. we both knew it looked like it should work. scott spotted it. and I am in his debt.